# Regex omit character but still replace (negative character class)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to replace "Franz" for anything else like "XXXX", but I would like to preserve some characters and not touch entirely other people.

What I have:

```
Franziska OpenShift
Franz! Kubernetes
@Franz Kubernetes
Franz, Kubernetes
```

What I want:

```
Franziska OpenShift
XXXX! Kubernetes
@XXXX Kubernetes
XXXX, Kubernetes
```

Where did I end up so far with `Franz[^i]`:

```
Franziska OpenShift
XXXX Kubernetes
@XXXXKubernetes
XXXX Kubernetes
```

It is consuming one more invisible character that I would like, or next character like `,!` etc.

I would appreciate help kind of lost here.

Comment: Use `Franz(?!i)`

Comment: This qustion got closd while I was typing an answer. Simply use word boundaries (if you are Ok with numbers and `_` as part of word chars) : `\bFranz\b`

Comment: wow thank you both answers are the solution! ^^